# Using matplotlib LineCollection, lines are not shown for particular coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would really appreciate some insight into a bug i'm experiencing.

In short, I'm animating the smooth transition from one LineCollection into another. So, in each LineCollection, I pair up lines, one from LineCollection A, and one from LineCollection B, and as time progresses, I change the coordinates of one line into the other. Every timestep, I can save the frame to a png. (In the final code I just grab the RGB data and feed it directly into a video writer, without saving the image, but it doesn't matter here).

The weird thing is, for very short lines, sometimes they just disappear. I could live with it if there's just a minimum length, but they can disappear and reappear several times during the animation, even if the lines are mapped linearly to each other over time. (Think of each coordinate tuple as a Linear Bezier curve in time. [Linear Bezier Curves.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Linear_B%C3%A9zier_curves)) So how can they become too short and then long enough over and over again?

[Check out the progression in these frames, which are about 3% of the total video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzFLL.jpg)

For instance, pay attention to the little balls on the bottom right.

Anyone have any idea why Matplotlib/LineCollections do this?

Comment: If anyone is interested in the final result, here is the full video: https://imgur.com/a/H4h67Gi

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone will be able to help you without a piece of code reproducing the problem. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have

lc= mc.LineCollection(Segments)

The answer is to use the LineCollection command

lc.set_snap(False)

As I expected it had to do with some optimization of the backend. set_snap as a default moves the location of an point to the nearest integer, but only on horizontal or vertical segments. This behavior was also only on rasterized output, not svg for instance. Every so many frames, the nearest pixel probably coincided for the start- and end-point of the segment, and it won't plot a line of length 0, even with a fat round cap style. On other frames this optimization wasn't applied because the line wasn't exactly vertical or horizontal, or it was applied but just happened to put the points on different pixels. I think for applications like this where pme wants full control, it's best to have all 'smart' optimization turned off, or one get quirks like this.

Thanks Diziet for helping me to understand this site. I'm not at liberty to put the whole code out there, and I was working on an example I could share, but I already found the solution.